# Can't create partition on Pendrive

Tags: connector

Once I removed my pendrive forcefully while it copying some files. To be specific, I had cancelled the operation but it was taking too much time to cancel it.

Now I can't open the pendrive. It shows nothing after formatting too. I have tried all Diskpart steps to resolve it. Tried Gparted too.

When I format it on my Zorin OS's Disk, it shows some error like

[image]

Comment: Your USB drive is toast. Into the trash it goes.

Comment: Yet to be proven IMO.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: @jsotola It's fairly clear what problem OP is trying to solve. If you think formulating it into a question adds value, feel free to use the [Edit] button

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to format the disk available as /dev/sdc ...

Now it is often better to first create a partition table and a single partition, then format that; without the partitioning; strange things happens at times as that differs from the "normal".

`$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=1`
should clean up any strange things on that disk (remnants of a filesystem)

Then do:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
[sudo] password for hannu: 

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): g    # create a new empty GPT partition table
...
Command (m for help): n    # add a new partition
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-19535251, default 2048):
...
Command (m for help): w    # write table to disk and exit
...
$
```

Note that, until that `w` has been launched, you may 'bail out' with `q`
As it has been done, try to format the disk.

Comment: _"without the partitioning; strange things happens at times"_ - true, but not this kind of strange things. `mkntfs` can create a filesystem inside everything, even in regular files. This flash drive is dead.

Comment: Maybe yes, but the above is a sane way to do things, and might now fail, and **most importantly** show us some kind of interpretable error text instead of the gibberish we see before this.

Comment: I seriously doubt trying to partition a dead flashdrive is going to make mkntfs work.

Comment: @Hannu I had already tried to create partition table via gparted but it resulted in input/output error. Now I tried your commands also but it gave me  `1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 32.7994 s, 32.0 kB/s`

Comment: If it's dead drive, in this electronics `superuser` world, can someone has solution to this hardware problem? I mean sorting some connections or renewing some parts on flash drive or some drivers?. I have Toshiba U202 pendrive

Comment: @Satyam ok, your cleared the portion of the drive that normally holds partitioning information; so how about the partitioning NOW? Thi will either "proove" that the drive is dead, or you will be able to at least examine whether it works in a higher degree or not.

Comment: Generally a "pendrive" may contain e.g. two integrated circuits; one to handle the connection to the outer world (via USB) possibly containing the flash memory "handler" separate from the flash, and one that contains the flash memory. May also be that these either already are single-chip or will become. Not much to repair there,